# Is there something wrong with my activity_main.xml?

Tags: java, android

I have noticed that my **activity_main** is different from others I have seen on YouTube.
Is there something wrong with mine?

Mine is blue while others have a more realistic and different layout.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks normal to me... I'm afraid I don't get the problem

Comment: Can you provide a definition for `a more realistic ... layout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videos in youtube had blank activity (As far as I have seen).The newer version of android studio (2.2.2 for your case) has empty and basic activity. You are in empty activity. Hence you get this beautiful blue UI instead of old look.[image: Like this]

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :) @RashidRaoufi

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity_main.xml` looks good. 
Maybe you were watching older videos, because it seems you're using the latest Android Studio Version.

To make your activity more realistic, you could add some `EditText` Element or `TextView`s and place them, wherever they look good (those elements are on the left side of your second screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The blue colors you see are the ***primary*** and ***dark primary*** colors. They can be found in your `colors.xml` file.

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
```

You will also find a pink color, that would be your ***accent*** color.

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

These are the default colors generated by **Android Studio** for you. You can change their values at any time to adjust the colors you need for your application.